# Redirecht to new domain (.htaccess - 301)

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-redirect

We crated a redesign for our shop and changed the URL structure for the languages.

For german language it was:
http://www.domain.com/product/

New it is:
http://www.domain.com/de/product/

For french it was:
http://fr.domain.com/product/

New it is:
http://www.domain.com/fr/product/

How can I achieve that the product pages will be redirectet to the specific language?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules **just below `RewriteEngine On`** in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond ^product/ http://www.domain.com/de%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fr\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond ^product/ http://www.domain.com/fr%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,NC,R=301]
```